# I know the answer to this program but I don't understand why?

Tags: c

I understand there is an increment of ii and x shifts left, but how does it go from 1 to being 3? Then from 13(D) to being 69? and so on...

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    int ii;
    for (ii = 0; ii < 8; ii++) {
        x = (x << ii) | 1;
        printf("0x%.8X\n", x);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

and This is the output

```
0x00000001

0x00000003

0x0000000D

0x00000069

0x00000691

0x0000D221

0x00348841

0x1A442081
```

Comment: I would think adding just one more `printf` statement to that loop, printing `x << ii` before the reassignment, would answer most of your questions.

Comment: I suggest that you step through the code yourself. Write the binary representation of each number and perform the operations by hand.

Comment: The pertinent question to ask is "what is the result of `(x << ii)`"?  I think if you figure that out, you'll understand the results. :-)

Comment: Reading hex numbers makes this task difficult. To understand what is going on, you need to convert the numbers to binary. Then you will easily see the patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write everything on a paper in binary to understand it, like that:

1 = 0000 0001

i:1 ... 0000 0010 | 0000 0001 = 0000 0011 (hex: 3)

i:2 ... 0000 1100 | 0000 0001 = 0000 1101 (hex: d)

i:3 ... 0110 1000 | 0000 0001 = 0110 1001 (hex: 69)

i:4 ... etc.